# Menu item URL not updating using MenuLinkManagerInterface::updateDefinition()

Tags: 8, navigation

When trying to update an existing menu link URL/ URI with updateDefinition() -

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkManagerInterface.php/function/MenuLinkManagerInterface%3A%3AupdateDefinition/8.2.x

It's noticed the url is not getting updated. Other key such as 'title', 'menu_name', 'description', 'enabled' etc gets updated.

This is expected as these are the keys that are allowed to override.
I'm trying to override a url or route of an existing menu item. 
Is there any other way I can achieve this? 
Below is my current implementation -

```
$menu_name = 'custom';
$menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
$parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);

$tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
$manipulators = array(
  array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
  array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
);
$tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);

foreach ($tree as $item) {
  //update existing menu item.
  $item->link->updateLink(
      [
        'enabled'=> 0,
        'title'=>'new name',
        'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node/1000'],  //Need to update to a new internal url.
        'menu_name' => 'custom',
      ],
      true
   );

}
```

I'm open for any suggestions/ ideas. Thanks!